# Custom Link clicking through a Javascript New Window

Tags: javascript, custom-link

I don't know exactly how to word this question but I will try my best and if you need clarification, please ask!  Thank you in advance for any insight and help you offer.

I created a custom link on the Account and Leads object that passes a number to a government website to see if someone has transportation authority.  The link only populates the number in the appropriate field but still requires the agent to click the search button.  Is there a way to write the link in such a fashion that it will:

1) populate the field as usual
2) click the search button and actually populate the information?

Here is the link for reference.  I am unsure how to write the link so that it will click through if at all possible.

Link:  http://li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LIVIEW/pkg_carrquery.prc_carrlist?n_docketno=648624

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible unless you have control of the site you are redirecting to.

Once you navigate to the other website, you do not hold the control over execution.

The best way to achieve this would be to check if the site offers an API and use it. I believe JavaScript hacks will not work.

---

If you have the control of the site you are redirecting to, you can achieve it via JS functions.

Comment: I figured that was the case but wanted to double check. What a bummer! Oh well, back to the drawing. Thank you, however, for pointing me into asking about an API!